# Opening a new file in Notepad++ makes my right side window centered

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, notepad++

Whenever I double click a file to open in windows explorer while notepad++ is already opened, it will center and minimize the notepad++ window a little bit. This is annoying.

Any ideas on how to keep my window right side justified when I open another file?

I am using Windows 7, and just downloaded Notepad++ 6.2.3.

Comment: How does the Notepad++ window look when first opened, before you move it to the right and resize? Perhaps it's just getting reset to its initial size and position?

Comment: Yep, I think you are right. Still, how can I keep it from moving out of  position once I do move it?

Comment: Since it's most likely Notepad++'s fault, you can try asking the developers if they can fix the bug and not make it move/resize if a new file is opened and displayed in an existing instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an easy workaround:

Just drag your files into the N++ window to open them (instead of double-clicking, right-click & open with, etc.).